# Force the user to enter an specified range of numbers in ASP.NET Core Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is there any way to force the user to enter an specified range of numbers in ASP.NET Core Model and if its not entered the desired range, shows a non validated message in the view after submitting the form?

```
    [Key]
    public int ExampleId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Number")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the {0}, It should be between 1 and 100.")]
    public int Number { get; set; }
```

I know how to display a message if user didn't enter the required field. But is it possible to show a non validated data when a user enters a number for example when its above 100?
I don't want to check it by javascript. I just want to know if its possible in this way?

Comment: Try with the [Range] attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is `Range`. You can specify what values are min and max they can add.

`[Range(0, 101, ErrorMessage = "The field {0} must be greater than {1} and less than {2}.")]`

This above says that the value must be between 1 and 100.

For more information please see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Thanks. It should be greater or less or it can be equal to them too? I meant 1 and 100 are acceptable ?

Comment: @Javad-M I suppose you could do 0 and 101 in that case